# hide attached images of a post

Tags: attachments, gallery, twitter-bootstrap

I've read an [article](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-your-own-image-gallery-page-template-in-wordpress--wp-23721) on how to implement a custom Gallery template in wordpress posts or pages. I have a simple question, is it possible to not show the attached images inside the post content but only inside my custom bootstrap carousel that I've coded with the gallery template?

here is the code I'm using (I'm not experienced with wordpress because usually I use laravel or plain php for my projects).

What I want to do is to show the attached media only inside the carousel, with my code for now the images are loaded also inside the post and this is not what I expect. Another question is about the bootstrap navwalker. I've a parent page that has four child pages, but I'm only able to click on the page name inside the menu to show the dropdown with the child pages. How i can fix this? 
Thanks for your help

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Gallery
 */
get_header();
?>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
<?php if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

<?php
  $args = array(
      'numberposts' => -1, // Using -1 loads all posts
      'orderby' => 'menu_order', // This ensures images are in the order set in the page media manager
      'order'=> 'ASC',
      'post_mime_type' => 'image', // Make sure it doesn't pull other resources, like videos
      'post_parent' => $post->ID, // Important part - ensures the associated images are loaded
      'post_status' => null,
      'post_type' => 'attachment'
  );
  $images = get_children( $args );
  $count = 0;
?>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 text-justify">
      <h2 class=""><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
<?php if($images): ?>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="">
        <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner" id="">
<?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
            <div class="carousel-item <?php echo ($count == 0) ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
              <img class="img-responsive d-block w-100" src="<?php echo $image->guid; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->post_title; ?>" title="<?php echo $image->post_title; ?>" />
            </div>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

What I want to do is to show the attached media only inside the carousel, with my code for now the images are loaded also inside the post and this is not what I expect. Another question is about the bootstrap navwalker. I've a parent page that has four child pages, but I'm only able to click on the page name inside the menu to show the dropdown with the child pages. How i can fix this? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: The Bootstrap menu opens on click by default, you can find a solution here: [How to implement a Navbar Dropdown Hover in Bootstrap v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183672/how-to-implement-a-navbar-dropdown-hover-in-bootstrap-v4)

Answer (score 1):

My first recommendation would be to use [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to setup a gallery rather than using this method.

However, I think you may be able to load your images using `Add Media -> Create Gallery` which will add a shortcode to your post content

```
[gallery ids="56,57,58"]
```

You could then use [the_content filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) and [strip_shortcodes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/strip_shortcodes/) to remove this shortcode from `the_content();` on your template. Hopefully you can then use [get_post_gallery()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_gallery/) or [get_post_gallery_images(](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_gallery_images/)) to retrieve the images you need for your carousel.

But try Advanced Custom Fields - it's much easier!

Comment: thanks, i will take a look to `get_post_gallery_images()` reference. I need the url. Thanks a lot for the suggestion of ACF, I know that plugin. Good.

Comment: That function should give you the image URLs. ACF is fantastic and we use it on most sites that we build. If I wanted to do something similar to your question, that's what I'd use. Good luck.